# Azure CDN Not Caching Images

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I'm using Azure CDN for Azure Blob image uploads but it doesn't seem to be correctly caching images on my website.

I've set the Blob Cache-Control: max-age=4233600 and it seems to work when I directly call from the blob URL. However, calling from the CDN URL shows max-age=0. I'm not sure if I've missed something, but I can't see any way to edit the CDN's Cache-Control. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the Cache to 'Public'? This allows all downstream servers to cache the response

Comment: I'm using Cloudberry Explorer for Azure Blob Storage, and I set tried setting "Cache-Control: public, max-age:4233600" but it still didn't work